# android: update UI from another thread in another class

Tags: android, multithreading

The scenario is
I have two threads and a UI thread. The UI thread when clicked on login button creates a ClientThread which creates a socket and runs until the socket is connected, whenever a message is received i use a handler to post message to another thread called ProcessDataThread, now on receiving some messages from server i need to update UI related stuff from ProcessDataThread, I searched around alot and i found these two ways runonUiThread function which i guess can only be run from the Activity Class which is useless and the Asynctask method which i am not sure how to pass the activity context to...

Here is the code

**The code executed when clicked on Login Button in the MainActivity**

```
public void onLoginClick(View view)
{
    global_constants.clientObject = new ClientThread();
    global_constants.clientThread = new Thread(global_constants.clientObject);
    global_constants.clientThread.start();
}
```

**The code in ClientThread run method**

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
.......
    @Override
    public void run() {
    ......
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && (!CloseThread))
        {
            byte[] buff;
            ....
            global_constants.updateConversationHandler.post(new ProcessDataThread(buff));
        }
    }
}
```

**The method code in ProcessDataThread after parsing out the incoming data and stuff**

```
public class ProcessDataThread implements Runnable {
.........
    void ProcessLoginFailedPacket(byte[] buff)
    {
        // how to call the UI thread from here for updating some UI elements??
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

i stored the activity context in a global variable and then did it this way, but i dont know whether it will be safer or not

```
((Activity)global_constants.MainContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        TextView txtErr = (TextView) ((Activity)global_constants.MainContext).findViewById(R.id.errMsg);
        txtErr.setVisibility(0);
        txtErr.setText(reason);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can post a runnable which does the UI operation to main thread as follows,

```
public class Utils {

    public static void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable){
        final Handler UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        UIHandler .post(runnable);
    } 
}

Utils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // UI updation related code.
     }
});
```

Comment: Should i make another public class file for this? and would this work if i have more than one activity? which activity will it work for or all activities are handled by a single thread? and finally how can i find a view id (e.g a textview or edittext) from the ui updation code area as i cant seem to use findViewById in there

Comment: I have made it as separate class so that this can be used where ever required.

Comment: Thanks, but i still cant find a way to use findViewById there... I found another way too, i am posting it in an edit in the main question, can you please let me know which one will be more safer to use.

Comment: It's generally not advisable to store the activity context globally and access it anywhere as they can lead to memory leaks in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, so i am again back to the question, how can i find an element in view from the runinUIThread method? it wont allow me to use findviewbyid if i dont store a context globally and typecast it the way i did

Comment: Either you can pass the view object around to the thread and from there to the runnable updating the UI. But that's not cleaner IMO. One alternative is to have an interface let's say - interface UIUpdater with a method callupdateUI(Data data). You can make the activity implement that interface and can pass around the interface object to the Thread and there by pass it on to runnable to notify the Acitivity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52330/discussion-between-user3448776-and-junaid-noor)